# Mobile Application Security

Tags: android, ios, security, mobile

We have an application in both iOS and android platform. We are coders from a municipality and our applications contains our city's transportation infos, our services, news etc. Instead of our offical application, another programmers have cracked our application and our services are compromised. They used our services and released another application. I decompiled one of their apk and saw our webservice address, username and password.

How can we secure our application in both iOS and Android platform?? Its like prevent their applications to access our services or maybe prevent their cracking offical applications. 
If we used, bearer authentication, we had to add username and password into our application. 
At soap services, we added username and password encrypted, but now they cracked app, and they used same encrypted username password and access to our services.

I cant figure out how can we secure our applications and prevent illegal access into our services.

Comment: Wouldn't a better solution be to offer other programmers access to this information via a documented and supported Web service?

Comment: If our superiors are decided that, its will be fine. But instead of that, they used our services illegally.

Comment: Then focus on having your superiors talk to qualified legal counsel regarding the "illegal" access to discuss specific legal remedies. From the technical side, disable their username on your server. None of this has anything to do with iOS or Android, so you might want to edit your question and explain, in detail, what you mean by "secure our application".

Comment: I've added more detail for my question. Our superiors probably wont want to their access. Because at future, we will add ask questions to our city's PR. and save directly their applications. We will add this service if we prevent this.

Comment: Check this https://medium.com/@mittal2810/how-to-safe-app-from-reverse-engineering-d4ca7910d2f

Answer (score 0):

A method would be to add in every web service an auth-key in the request's header. The user will get an auth-key when logging in or registering as a reply from your authentication service. This way you can simply cut access from any request that doesn't have an auth-key provided by your system.

Also you need to obfuscate your code, in android is quite simple to do that using proguard and gradle.

This isn't a fully secure solution, but it will give those guys some time until they can user your services again.

Comment: If I've add an auth-key in my header, they also access that in compromised situation. I've obfuscated my code at android but at ios i dont know is there any obfuscator.

Comment: The auth-key would be received after authenticating. so it should be your authentication service's role to manage who gains access to your data, and when they should get rejected.